# Best practice with many parameters in constructor?

Tags: c#

If I have a view which need access to 5 different repositories I am doing this right now :

```
public class MyClass
{
   private readonly IRepo1 rep1;
   private readonly IRepo2 rep2;
   ...
   public MyClass(IRepo1 r1, IRepo2 r2, IRepo3 r3, IRepo4 r4...)
   {
      rep1 = r1;
      rep2 = r2;
      re3 = r3;
   }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that constructor gets bigger and bigger and if something changes in the constructor, I have to edit changes all the way through the system. How to avoid this problem?

I thought about creating a builder class which would be responsible for creating repositories and parse them to the views. Or is this a bad approach?

Comment: If you have a huge bunch of dependencies (which is what you obviosuly provide within your constructor) you probably have an error on your design as your class is doing to much. Building a Repository-factory is therefor maybe a first good idea. mAybe better go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: What about a class you pass into the ctor as the one and only parameter? It is easy to add properties there without changing the calls. But HimBromBeere is right that this smells a bit...

Comment: Check into **depedency injection** - that's what it's designed to handle just nicely

Comment: Well its some code ive got from other developer, so i cant make big changes at 1 time. gonna make a simple class which i parse to viewmodels for now.

Comment: Introduce a service interface and class, which will contain all the repositories, and inject an instance of that service into the constructors of your classes. Another name could be: unit-of-work.

Answer (score -3):

You can make all your repository interfaces derive from a base interface `IRepositoryBase`, and then pass an `IEnumerable<IRepositoryBase>` to your constructor.

Also, since your repositories end up being handled by `MyClass` one way or another, they probably have some functionality in common; you can also add methods in `IRepositoryBase` for this common functionality, and then `MyClass` can do its work without the need to know the actual types of the repositories it's working on.

### Example code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IRepositoryBase[] repos; 

    public MyClass (IEnumerable<IRepositoryBase> r)
    {
        repos = r.ToArray();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This answer is awful.  Obviously, he isn't getting five copies of the *same* repository, so for this to work he'd have to look at the Type of each in the IEnumerable and cast it to the appropriate repository type in the constructor.  That's an **utterly awful design**.  The real solution is to use an IoC container to spin up your types and fill dependencies.  You can ditch constructor injection and move the repositories to properties.  Tell your friends/socks not to upvote your answers if they are this bad.

Comment: @Will The question author already checked this answer as accepted, so it makes sense.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Maybe the OP isn't seeing the long term consequences yet. I fully agree with Will.

Comment: I agree with @Will regarding using an IoC container.

Comment: @Will, can we see an answer with an example please?

Answer (score -5):

Instead of using dependency injection (which introduces reflection, making your code slower, insecure and less readable!) you can make use of the builder pattern to initialize `MyClass` instances:

**MyClassBuilder.cs**:

```
public class MyClassBuilder {
    IRepo1 rep1;
    IRepo2 rep2;
    IRepo3 rep3;
    IRepo4 rep4;
    // ...

    public MyClassBuilder() {

    }

    public MyClassBuilder setRepo1(IRepo1 rep1) {
        this.rep1 = rep1;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClassBuilder setRepo2(IRepo2 rep1) {
        this.rep2 = rep2;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClassBuilder setRepo3(IRepo3 rep3) {
        this.rep3 = rep3;
        return this;
    }

    public MyClassBuilder setRepo4(IRepo4 rep4) {
        this.rep4 = rep4;
        return this;
    }
    // ...

    public MyClass build() {
        return new MyClass(
            rep1 ?? DEFAULT_REP1,
            rep2 ?? DEFAULT_REP2,
            rep3 ?? DEFAULT_REP3,
            rep4 ?? DEFAULT_REP4
            // ...
        );
    }
}
```

**Example usage**:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClassBuilder()
    .setRepo1(new Repo1(/*...*/))
    .setRepo4(new Repo4(/*...*/))
    .build();
```

Comment: Why does dependency injection use reflection? This is absolutely not true.

Comment: You realise you are injecting dependencies in your example, right?

Comment: @Maarten http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/06/30/dependency-injection-is-dead.aspx

Comment: You are using a form of poor mans DI.  You are injecting dependencies for IRepo1, IRepo2, IRepo3 and IRepo4 and using defaults if those are not injected.

Comment: DI does not just refer to the use of IoC containers.